# Generic Error When Using 'Actions & Recommendations' / 'Guided Actions'

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows, setup

### Issue

I receive the following error when attempting to use an object-specific quick Action via the 'Actions & Recommendations' Lightning Component:

[image: Error message]

### Background

- 'Actions & Recommendations' were previously called 'Guided Actions'.
- We're trying to use this feature to highlight next steps that a user should perform after they create a certain custom object record.
- An 'Actions & Recommendations' deployment for a custom
  object has been created.
- Type of guidance is set to 'Flows and quick actions'.
- Two object-specific quick Actions were created on the custom object, added to the page layout, and added to the 'default' channel of the deployment.
- The 'Actions & Recommendations' Lightning Component was added to the custom object's page layout, the quick Actions appear after clicking 'Add', but they don't appear in the panel itself (below the 'Add' button):

[image: Actions & Recommendations quick Actions]

### Question

Any idea why this error appears and how can I resolve it?

And why don't my quick Actions appear in the panel under the 'Add' button?

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce support has confirmed that this is due to a bug with 'Actions & Recommendations' and custom objects: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001PYcdQAG